# Apache dosn’t load virtual host files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server

I’m trying to set up an Apache2 server, but I can’t get it to load my virtual hosts. Or to be more precise, it works fine as long as I write them in `000-default.conf`, but whenever I try to use a separate file it seem to completely ignore it.

Why is this not working? And how do I make it work?

Comment: Check you `httpd.conf` file, it should contain a line like Include `conf/*.conf`. Check whether it is a wildcard or a fixed file (like `000-default.conf`). Also, check that your new conf files match the wildcard patern and are stored on the same folder as the `000-default.conf`. Finally, there are apache distributions where they have a `available` and a `active` conf files, so in some cases a soft link is needed in order for it to work.

Comment: NuTTyX was right though

Answer (score 5):

Typically if one wants to setup separate virtual host configurations, you would place them in this directory:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/
```

So if you have a virtual host named `www.example.com` the config filename can be named `www.example.com.conf` like this:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/www.example.com.conf
```

You would then open that file in a text editor like this; I’m using `nano` as an example but feel free to use whatever text editor you prefer:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/www.example.com.conf
```

And then place content similar to this into `www.example.com.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin admin@example.com
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Close and save that file and then use `a2ensite` like this to have the system set a symbolic link from `sites-available` to `sites-enabled` like this:

```
sudo a2ensite www.example.com.conf
```

Or—if you wanted to—you could manually use `ln -s` to set a symbolic link like this:

```
ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/www.example.com.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www.example.com.conf
```

When that’s done just reload Apache like this:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

And if for some reason `reload` doesn’t work, just force a restart like this:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

The benefit of using `reload` before `restart` is that if there is a typo in a config file, Apache will report an error but not load the config files. Meaning your Apache web server will still be up and running based on the last stable configuration file it loaded.

The risk is that if you force a `restart` and there is a typo in a configuration file, Apache will be dead because `restart` forces a complete service `stop` followed by a `start`. And if that `start` chokes, the server is dead until the config typo/issue is cleared up.

Answer (score 2):

Check you `httpd.conf` file, it should contain a line like `Include conf/*.conf`. Check whether it is a wildcard or a fixed file (like `000-default.conf`).

Also, check that your new conf files match the wildcard patern and are stored on the same folder as the `000-default.conf`.

Finally, there are apache distributions where they have a available and a active conf files, so in some cases a soft link is needed in order for it to work